# What does the Scale parameter mean in linear regression?

Tags: spss, generalized-linear-model

I have started to use the `GENLIN` procedure in SPSS more than any of the specific dialogues, but I don't understand the Scale parameter or why it has the effects it does on the regression results.

Here's an SPSS example: *code block 1*

Normally, if I wanted to see if *set* has an effect on the linear parameters $b_0$ and $b_1$, I'd could just do linear regression with the interaction term *set1X*: *code block 2*

The results are obvious: *set* affects slope but not the intercept of my model (as I'd expect since I generated these sample data that way). But if I use `GENLIN` instead of `REGRESSION`, my sig. values and 95%CIs for the parameters are different: *code block 3*

This Scale parameter (regressed by `GENLIN` as 1.127 with a SE of 0.3563) seems to make the difference. If I change the scale to `PEARSON` (for Pearson's chi sq.), `DEVIANCE` (?), or a constant like 1, I get all different answers.

**Summary**: what is Scale in Generalized Linear Models (`GENLIN` in SPSS) and how should I handle it? Why doesn't OLS Linear regression use such a parameter? How do I know how to assign scale?

### Code block 1

```
data list list /X set Y.
begin data.
1   1   7.0
2   1   7.8
3   1   12.4
4   1   14.8
5   1   19.0
6   1   22.7
7   1   24.4
8   1   25.5
9   1   29.5
10  1   31.0
1   2   7.9
2   2   12.7
3   2   14.3
4   2   20.1
5   2   20.8
6   2   26.5
7   2   30.9
8   2   35.8
9   2   38.0
10  2   43.7
end data.
dataset name exampleData WINDOW=front.
variable level X (scale) Y (scale) set (nominal).

compute set1 = (set=1).
compute set1X = set1*X.
EXECUTE.
```

### Code block 2

```
REGRESSION
  /MISSING LISTWISE
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS CI(95) R ANOVA CHANGE
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT Y
  /METHOD=FORWARD X set1 set1X.
```

### Code block 3

```
* Generalized Linear Models.
GENLIN Y BY set (ORDER=ASCENDING) WITH X
  /MODEL X set*X INTERCEPT=YES
 DISTRIBUTION=NORMAL LINK=IDENTITY
  /CRITERIA SCALE=MLE COVB=MODEL PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) 
    CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=WALD LIKELIHOOD=FULL
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

Comment: Scale parameter makes it possible to account for nonhomogeneity variances http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48237/3277

Comment: Does this apply to models that don't use probit or logit? My example specifically uses two continuous variables.

Does scale still just account for heteroscedasticity?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing "set" as an effect in GENLIN (in your MODEL statement) but you have it in REGRESSION. Try this:

```
GENLIN Y BY set (ORDER=ASCENDING) WITH X
  /MODEL set X set*X INTERCEPT=YES DISTRIBUTION=NORMAL LINK=IDENTITY
  /CRITERIA SCALE=MLE COVB=MODEL PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 
   ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=WALD LIKELIHOOD=FULL
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

That will give you the results you're looking for.

The scale parameter is actually called "dispersion" in most generalized linear model theory papers or articles. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384521/in-glms-are-the-scale-and-dispersion-parameters-the-same) for more information.